# Does Payflow_dotNET.dll No Longer works on Payflow Pilot Testing Endpoints pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com after 02/15/2017

Tags: dll, paypal, payflowpro

We have used Payflow_dotNET.dll several years.
In the past few days (after 2/17/2017)
, We found we cannot process payment on Payflow Pilot Testing Endpoints pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com

We got timeout or Result=-1 Faild to connect to host Input Server 
[image: Result -1]

or -32 The certificate chain not validate...
[image: Result -32]

We don't found any information said Payflow_dotNET.dll is **NOT** Working after 02/15/2017 PayPal Upgraded to TLS1.2 for Pilot Testing Endpoints.

**Our question is:**

- Does Payflow_dotNET.dll no Longer works on Payflow Pilot Testing
  Endpoints pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com?
- Does anyone has suggestion for us to change to use other APIs to
  replace it?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and found that you need to set  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to allow SecurityProtocolType.Tls12. In our case we used SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 and it seemed to work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. Had to add one line of code to my PayFlow wrapper class. Third line of the constructor here solved the problem.

```
public CardProcessor() {
        payFlowProUser = new UserInfo(USER, VENDOR, PARTNER, PWD);
        payFlowConnection = new PayflowConnectionData();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe PayPal is upgrading their security. Found a link on the same

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US